# Access to list items between two solutions (C#, Async)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-4.0, async-await

I have two solution:

**Sol1**:

```
 public class Sol1{

  internal override IList<MenuItem> MenuItems
  {
   //some code
   GetItems();

   return items;
  }

  internal override async void GetItems()
  {
    //code
    //async method
    //code
    //async method
  }
 }
```

Solution one is creating first first level of menu. Then into Solution 2, after fist level menu is created I want to have access to this "**items**".

**Sol2**:

```
public class Sol2{

  private async Task SecondLev{
     //some code
   Sol1 sol1 = new Sol1();
   var test = sol1.items;
  }
}
```

But they are always empty. I don't want to run one more time method **MenuItems**, but have access to this items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: Also you're not calling either `MenuItems` or `GetItems` in your `SecondLev` method.

Comment: And it seems like you want to switch from async (`SecondLev`) to non-async (`MenuItems`) to async (`GetItems`), this feels like a bad practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are empty, because you don't await async operation.

Your code should look like:

```
    public class Sol1
    {
        internal IList<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; private set; }

        internal async Task GetItems()
        {
            // some async code
            // ...
            MenuItems = someResult;
        }
    }

    public class Sol2
    {
        private async Task SecondLevel()
        {
            //some code
            Sol1 sol1 = new Sol1();
            await sol1.GetItems();
            var test = sol1.MenuItems;
        }
    }
```

Few notes:

1. Don't make `async void` methods if they are not an event handlers, use
   `async Task` instead.
2. You cannot have async properties, only async methods.